# Delphi WindowsMediaPlayer get volume stream

Tags: delphi

How do I get the audio stream output when playing a wav file with WindowsMediaPlayer?

```
WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := '...';
WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.play;

Example on audio stream receive..
ProgressBar.Position := VolumeOutput;
```

Comment: Your choice of words is quite confusing - do you want to know the current volume setting? It will always be the same, no matter which file you play. The loudness of an audio track is not guaranteed to be stable from start to end - it always changes.

Comment: If you are looking for VU meter values, [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984223/2292722). The discussion is from 2014. Whether it works in current systems, I don't know.